# mapper 3.x is not supported and flutter app not showing new changes

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk

The changes I am making in my app are not getting visible and the previous state is loading up... I changed the home to another screen in `main.dart` but the app is not opening on that screen. I am getting this in my debug console:

```
W/Gralloc3(16231): mapper 3.x is not supported
E/        (16231): APS:IFLoad:importExternalFunctions, search function createNewHwApsUtils failed, dlsym err:undefined symbol: createNewHwApsUtils
D/        (16231): APS:importExternalFunctions OK
I/HwViewRootImpl(16231): removeInvalidNode jank list is null
```